# Add index to runs of positive or negative values of certain length

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe, which contains 100.000 rows. It looks like this:

```
 Value
 1
 2
-1
-2
 0
 3
 4
-1
 3
```

I want to create an extra column (column B). Which consist of 0 and 1's.

It is basically 0, but when there are 5 data points in a row positive OR negative, then it should give a 1. But, only if they are in a row (e.g.: when the row is positive, and there is a negative number.. the count shall start again).

```
Value    B
 1       0
 2       0
 1       0
 2       0
 2       1
 3       1
 4       1
-1       0
 3       0
```

I tried different loops, but It didn't work. I also tried to convert the whole DF to a list (and loop over the list). Unfortunately with no end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses the `rollmean` function from the `zoo` package.

```r
set.seed(1000)
df = data.frame(Value = sample(-9:9,1000,replace=T))
sign = sign(df$Value)
library(zoo)
rolling = rollmean(sign,k=5,fill=0,align="right")
df$B = as.numeric(abs(rolling) == 1)
```

I generated 1000 values with positive and negative sets.

- Extract the `sign` of the values - this will be -1 for negative, 1 for positive and 0 for 0
- Calculate the right aligned rolling mean of 5 values (it will average x[1:5], x[2:6], ...).  This will be 1 or -1 if all the values in a row are positive or negative (respectively)
- Take the absolute value and store the comparison against 1.  This is a logical vector that turns into 0s and 1s based on your conditions.

Note - there's no need for loops.  This can all be vectorised (once we have the rolling mean calculated).

Comment: That is really clear Mark! It works, ty for that! But can you explain: align = "right" it bit more?

Comment: There are three `align` options - 'left', 'right' and 'center' (default).  Because `rollmean` is vectorised, it will return a vector of the same length as the input. When `align="right"` it means the mean of `x[1:5]` will be stored in `rolling[5]`. If `align="left"` then the mean of `x[1:5]` will be stored in `rolling[1]` and "center" would store it in `rolling[3]`

Comment: All that to say that in your case, `align="right"` means you're checking the last 5 values, `align="left"` would check the next 5.

Comment: Thnx! But I think that there is a little problem: with the fill argument = 0, we miss the first 4 data points (because they are filled as 0). 

So if i'm correct, it means that there is an error range (because the first 4 data points are filled as a 0. Or am I wrong? 

I found it out, because I wanted to do the same trick..: 5 data points on a row, but all increasing of decresing. There I faced the issue that the first 4 items are 0.

Comment: There are not 5 trailing points available for the first 4 points so the 5 point mean does not exist for them.   The fill= argument specifies what value to use when it can't be calculated.   If you omit fill=0 then it will omit those values returning a shorter vector.  You can also use `rollapplyr(x, width, mean, partial = TRUE)` to fill in the otherwise unfillable values with partial means.   See the `?rollapply` help page for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Not the most efficient way to do it but the logic is pretty transparent -- just check if there's only one unique sign (i.e. +, -, or 0) for each sequence of five adjacent rows:

```
dat <- data.frame(Value=c(1,2,1,2,2,3,4,-1,3))

dat$new_col <- NA
dat$new_col[1:4] <- 0

for (x in 5:nrow(dat)){
  if (length(unique(sign(dat$Value[(x-4):x])))==1){
    dat$new_col[x] <- 1
  } else {
    dat$new_col[x] <- 0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `cumsum(...diff(...) <condition>)` idiom to create a grouping variable, and `ave` to calculate the indices within each group.

```
d$B2 <- ave(d$Value, cumsum(c(0, diff(sign(d$Value)) != 0)), FUN = function(x){
  as.integer(seq_along(x) > 4)})

#   Value B B2
# 1     1 0  0
# 2     2 0  0
# 3     1 0  0
# 4     2 0  0
# 5     2 1  1
# 6     3 1  1
# 7     4 1  1
# 8    -1 0  0
# 9     3 0  0
```